# __FILE__ gives different result when built with CMake/ninja than when built with CMake/make

Tags: c++, cmake, c-preprocessor, ninja

`__FILE__` gives either an absolute path (built with make) or a relative one (built with ninja). Here's a simple tester:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::string thisFile = __FILE__;
    std::cout << "thisFile = " << thisFile << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

And here's the equally simple `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(file_test)

add_executable(app main.cpp)
```

If I'm in the `build` directory, I'll type either `cmake ..` or `cmake -GNinja ..` (I've also experimented with explicitly saying which c++ compiler to use with a `-D` argument on the command line - with unchanged results).

If I build with ninja, `app`'s output is:

```
thisFile = ../main.cpp
```

If I build with make, `app`'s output is:

```
thisFile = /home/myname/sandbox/cmake/main.cpp
```

I've tried this on Ubuntu and Pop!OS - same results.

Does anyone know of a way to get the ninja build to behave in the same way that the make build does?

Comment: The answer to your question is:  yes.  (Probably the `__FILE__` is set to whatever was passed in as the parameter to the compiler for the source file to compile.)

Comment: Apparently I asked the wrong question. Why would cmake create build files that fed different parameters to the compiler?

Comment: Why not? The compiler must be able to locate the file to compile. Thereby, (as well as with a lot of other applications) you have the choice of relative or absolute file paths. It seems you cannot rely on anything. - I once noticed that I got absolute file paths in VS2013 with x86 and relative with x64 (or vice versa). (Or was it VS2008? It's a while ago. I forgot...) ;-)

Comment: If you definitely need either absolute or relative file paths, you probably have to add some extra fiddling (maybe, even in custom code of the application itself). You could pass the source code file dir. as a macro (defined by yourself in the command line of the build script) and process `__FILE__` and that macro to turn the one into the other when necessary. `std::filesystem` will be helpful surely. AFAIR, you even cannot expect normalized file paths i.e. I once saw "trampoline" paths in mine e.g. something like `./src/../build/file.cc`. But, again: easy to fix with `std::filesystem`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does anyone know of a way to get the ninja build to behave in the same way that the make build does?

Use CMake 3.21, from [3.21 release notes](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/release/3.21.html?highlight=ninja%20absolute%20paths):

> The Ninja Generators now pass source files and include directories to the compiler using absolute paths. This makes diagnostic messages and debug symbols more consistent, and matches the Makefile Generators.

Alternatively, write a wrapper script around your compiler. Such a script would parse compiler options and extract source file path and change relative path to absolute and then invoke the compiler with absolute path. Pass that wrapper to CMake with `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_LAUNCHER` to launch your script.

Alternatively, in CMake iterate over every file you are going to compile, extract in CMake a full path to that file with `get_filename_component` and then use `set_source_file_properties` on that file to add `COMPILE_DEFINITION` like `ABSFILE=${the_absolute_path_to_that_file}` and use that compile definition in your source file for a full path. I think, probably depending on compiler, you could also overwrite `__FILE__` that way.